# nagios- nrpe installation error(configure: error: Cannot find ssl libraries)

Tags: ssl, network-monitoring, nagios3

i have installed nagios and i want to install nrpe. While installing NRPE, when i execute (/home/abc/nrpe/configure)

```
./configure
```

it stops after reaching the following line

```
...

checking for type of socket size... size_t
checking for SSL headers... SSL headers found in /usr
checking for SSL libraries... configure: error: Cannot find ssl libraries
```

I have installed libssl-dev and openssl package as i found them as a solution for this error.

I tried the following option also

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib
```

But the error remains.

What can be the possible solution for this ? I am using ubuntu 12.04 as my operating system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I found the dir through:

```
apt-file search libssl | grep libssl-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I end up with the installation of the older version of nrpe and that worked for me.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. For future reference, in what docs did you find those configure `--with` options?

Comment: I had to combine this with another answer, and install `libssl-dev` first.  `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: If you run it from a Raspberry with ubuntu, it should be ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 9):

I had similar issues on a Raspberry PI, after I'd installed the libssl-dev package

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

but managed to find the ssl lib for the configure command with this:

```
# dpkg -L libssl-dev

.
.
.
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so

# ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the following command to fix it:

`yum install openssl-devel`

Comment: Yum is not used in ubuntu. Should be sudo apt-get install openssl-devel

Answer (score 5):

With Ubuntu Server, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```